# Using case filter in Crystal reports formulas editor

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-xi

Could you please let me know how can i use below case statement in Crystal reports. Am using below case statement in filters part.  Basically trying to reject all the records where (a.xxx is null and a1.ayyy= example)

---

case when (a.XXX is NULL AND (a1.YYY=('example')OR a1.YYY=('example+')))

then 'Inactive'

Else 'Active'

End) = 'Active'

Comment: Can the same be accomplished using if then? am a SQL developer just need this filter to be added to one of our crystal report.

Comment: filter? Are you just looking to select all records that are 'Active'? or are you looking for a formula that out puts either 'Active" or 'Inactive'?

Comment: Am looking for all records that are active

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
stringvar status := "Active";
IF (ISNULL({a.XXX}) AND ({a.YYY} = "SomeValue" OR {a.YYY} = "SomeOtherValue") ) THEN
    status:='Inactive'
ELSE 
    status;
status;
```

Comment: Can we use this along with the Parameter value? am getting syntax error

Comment: yes you can. use the {?ParameterName} = '<value to check>'

Comment: Thanks.. what am trying here is trying to reject the records from record selection based on the conditions above

Comment: could you please help

Comment: send me your email and we can start a conversation there. It should be easy